# JavaFx- ListView manipulation from database

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to manipulate ListView from the data that will be retrieved from a database column, but for some reason, I am not able to do that. I even tried to print the list but it did not return anything. Am is missing something very obvious here?

Here's my code:

```
public void manipulateListView() {
    List<String> listViewItems = new ArrayList<>();
    resultSet = null;
    uID = userIDLabel.getText();
    String selectCategories = " SELECT Title  FROM video_category WHERE userID = ? ";
    try {
        conn = DbConnector.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectCategories);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, uID);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {

            listViewItems.add(resultSet.getString("Title"));


        }


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TutorControlPanelController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

      ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listViewItems);
            categoryListView.setItems(observableList);

}
```

Comment: So can you tell us what actually happens? Is there anything in the result set? Do you get any exceptions? Where are you calling this method from? Where is `categoryListView` defined and initialized?

Comment: No exception. event result set is empty. there are 5 entries in the database.  I have executed query in MySQL workbench it's returning results.

Comment: Then something is wrong in the SQL/JDBC. Probably for some reason the value in the label (weird: why on earth are you getting the value from a label?) is not matching the userID in the database column. Maybe post the database table description (from `describe video_categories;` in MySQL).

Comment: you are right mate! there  is something wrong with the uID scope, which is basically userIDLabel.getText(). but what annoys me is the other method which is working fine with uID.